# Classification of primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Carry on with [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174605) I have the following question.

Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable, $f(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial, $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$ and $\theta$ = $X$ (mod $f(X)$). Can we classify all the primary ideals of $A$?

a. If a prime ideal $P$ of $A$ is principal then $P$-primary ideals are prime power.

b. If $P=(p, g(\theta))$ (see, [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174605)) then can we describe $P$-primary ideals in this case?

Comment: I will point out that the tag (abstract-algebra) is deprecated on [mathoverflow.se], see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info). The question was posted also on [math.se] (a few days ago): [Classification of primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408247).

Comment: Case $P=(p,g(\theta))$: If $p^2$ doesn't divide $disc(f)$ then $A_p$ is a Dedekind domain and the $P$-primary ideals are the powers of $P$.

Comment: @DavidLampert Thank you, Sir. For example, if we take $f(x)=X^2+4$, then except $(2, X)$-primary ideals all other primary ideals are a prime power.

Comment: @TimCampion. I am sorry, can I know what is MSE?

Comment: Dear Sir, @DavidLampert. In particular, can we say anything about $(2, x)$-primary ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+4)$, where $x$ denotes the image of $X$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+4)$.

Comment: MSE = Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TusifAhmed   With $f(x)=x^2+4, P=(2,x)$ the $P$-primary ideals are: $(2^n), (2^{n-1}x), P^n=(2^n, 2^{n-1}x), n \ge 1$.  Nice example.

Comment: @DavidLampert, Thank you very much, Sir. So in this example, one can see the complete class of primary ideals. Can I know the trick on how you get all of these? Much obliged.

Comment: @TimCampion, many thanks.

Comment: @DavidLampert I notice that $(2+x)$ and $(2-x)$ are also $P$-primary because of $(2+x)^2==4x$ and $(2-x)^2=-4x$.

Comment: @DavidLampert From the above-mentioned primary ideals, one can get the following new ones. $(2^n, 2+x)$ and $(2^n, 2-x)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @TusifAhmed You are right, my list of $P$-primary ideals was incomplete, thanks for the correction.  In addition to the new ones that you identified, there are: $(2x+4), (2x-4), (8,2x+4)$.

Comment: @DavidLampert, many thanks. In fact from these new ones we get, $(2^nx+2^{n+1}), (2^nx-2^{n+1}), (2^n, 2^kx+2^{k+1}), (2^n, 2^kx-2^{k+1})$ where $k<n$.  I think it completes the  class of $(2, x)$-primary ideals

Comment: @TusifAhmed Thanks.  I think we have identified all the primary ideals.  Note there are redundancies in the descriptions e.g. $(x+2)=(x+2, 8)$.

Comment: @DavidLampert, thank you very much, Sir, for arising this point. I will think about the irredundant ones and try to remove the repetition from the list. I repost my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3416194) by changing arbitrary polynomial to quadratic one. I mentioned all these primary ideals as an example. I need your review on it and answers or at least a hint for moving in the right direction.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: @TusifAhmed I enjoyed working with you on this problem.  I think it can be a guide to similar problems of your interest and I'm sorry I don't have more time now for them.

Comment: @DavidLampert. Thank you for your great help.